# logistic regression and AIC - can't replicate statsmodels' AIC manually in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels, metrics

I would like to calculate AIC from logistic regression from sklearn. However, none of my manually coded metrics match the output from statsmodels: R^2, adjusted R^2, AIC, log likelihood. Can you help find where I miscoded my metrics in sklearn?

```
# Import
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tools import add_constant

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from math import log

from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Dataset
n = 100
data = {'CO2': np.random.normal(14, 3, n),
        'NO2': np.random.normal(96, 2, n),
        'Outcome': np.random.choice([0,1], 
                                  size=100, 
                                  p=[0.7, 0.3])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df.head())

# Split
X = df.drop(columns=['Outcome'])
Y = df[['Outcome']]
Y = Y.values.ravel()

# sklearn 
logreg = LogisticRegressionCV(penalty="l1", fit_intercept = True, 
                              solver="saga", 
                              cv=5, random_state=0, max_iter=1000, scoring='accuracy')
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# negative log-likelihood of a logistic model that returns y_pred probabilities for its training data y_true

yhat = logreg.predict(X)
Y_yhat_df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': Y, 'yhat': yhat})
# print(Y_yhat_df.head())

logloss = round(log_loss(Y, yhat), 4)
print('log loss: %s' % logloss)

loglike = -1 * logloss
print('log likelihood: %s' % loglike)

mse = mean_squared_error(Y, yhat)
print('MSE: %s' % round(mse, 2))

# Model parameters
k = X.shape[1]
print('k: %s' % k)

n = len(X)
print('n: %s' % n)

num_params = logreg.coef_.shape[-1]
print('Parameters: %s' % num_params)
# print(logreg.coef_)

print('R2: %s' % round(logreg.score(X, Y), 2))

# Adjusted R^2
R2adj = 1 - (1-logreg.score(X, Y))*(len(Y)-1)/(len(Y)-X.shape[1]-1)
print('R2 adj: %s' % round(R2adj, 2))

# 2k - 2(log(log likelihood))
# np.log is the natural log
aic = 2*num_params - 2 * (-1 * np.log(logloss))
print('AIC: %s' % round(aic,2))

bic = n * log(mse) + num_params * log(n)
print('BIC: %s' % round(bic, 2))

# Stats models

# Manually add intercept 
Xi = sm.add_constant(X)

sm_logreg = sm.Logit(Y, Xi)

res = sm_logreg.fit_regularized(method='l1')

print(res.aic)
print(res.summary())
```

#### sklearn output

- log loss: 12.6153
- log likelihood: -12.6153
- MSE: 0.35
- k: 2
- n: 100
- Parameters: 2
- R2: 0.65
- R2 adj: 0.64
- AIC: 9.07 BIC: -95.77

#### statsmodels output

- AIC: 134.88348802189196
- Pseudo R-squ.: 0.004679 (adjusted R^2)
- Log-Likelihood: -64.442

Comment: `print('R2: %s' % round(logreg.score(X, Y), 2))` score() is defined as accuracy for classifiers, not as R^2.

Comment: Ah right -- thanks. Is my AIC formula okay?

Comment: You appear to be taking the log of log loss. That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data generated above, I ran another logistic regression model in R.

The output generated was as follows:

```
> model <- glm(y ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=mydata)
> summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mydata)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -19.11482   12.58023  -1.519    0.129
co2           0.08343    0.07229   1.154    0.248
no2           0.17766    0.13005   1.366    0.172

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 122.17  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 118.85  on 97  degrees of freedom
AIC: 124.85

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

> AIC(model)
[1] 124.8456
```

With an AIC of 124.85, this value is close to what the *statsmodels* output generated.

I am unsure as to why the AIC generated by sklearn differs greatly - but this is largely academic in any case. The purpose of using AIC is to compare fit across different models - the lower the AIC, the better.

The model generated does not currently show predictive power in its own right and thus using AIC to gauge the same is irrelevant without comparing with other models.